# EBPF Route Table Addition or Modification

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

Do EBPF has any interface Apis to add or modify route table.

I tried search but do not get any concrete Apis while bpf_fib_lookup Api do not meet my need, Basically I have to add a new route depending upon some specific condition.

Any input will be appreciable.

Regards

Comment: It does not. What's your use case?

Comment: Requirement is in some specific condition, i have to send traffic through underlay. I am able to hook at appropriate points to meet those specific condition, Since route table add/modify can be only feasible through user layer.
As far as i know we can only communicate from kernel layer to user layer through maps. we need real time notification mechanism from kernel to user layer, while maps work in polling mechanism
Do we have any specific mechanism to notify user layer from kernel layer in real time (like events, etc)?

Comment: Did you consider routing with eBPF itself?